# It is possible to get values from browser localstorage using python Requests-HTML?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

Ok I'm  using python Requests-HTML to scrape a dynamic website that store a baerer token on browser localstorage.

When I get the page and render it, the html content loads fine but when I try to get values from localstorage using a script this is empty.

```
        r = session.get('https://www.legis.ga.gov/legislation/63488')
        r.html.render(sleep=6)
        script = """
                () => {
                    return {
                        width: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                        height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                        deviceScaleFactor: window.devicePixelRatio,
                        location: location.href,
                        token: localStorage.token
                    }
                }
        """
        val = cheo.html.render(script=script)
        print(val)
```

{'width': 800, 'height': 600, 'deviceScaleFactor': 1, 'location': 'https://www.legis.ga.gov/legislation/63488'}

Another possible solution is check the "browser" network history of my session but i can't reach it either.

Someone knows if is posssible do this with python Requests-HTML?

I expect get the values stored on the localStorage or inspect the browser network traffic of the python request-html session.